# Compare all files to each other

Tags: bash

I will start by saying I have gotten this to work, and the question is about how improve the script to make it better/faster.

I need to compare a series of files to each other. Let's say I have the below files:

```
filename0   filename1   filename2
```

What I have done is:

```
Z=0 # Beginning number
Y=2 # Final number

X=$Z # Initial file number
((W=Y+1)) # Number for ranges

while [[ $Z -lt $W ]]
do
    while [[ $X -lt $W ]] 
    do
        obabel filename$Z.xyz -oconfabreport -xf filename$X.xyz -xr 0.2 > Results.$Z.$X
    ((X=X+1))
    done
    ((Z=Z+1))
    ((X=Z))
done
```

It compares files like this:

```
filename0 filename0
filename0 filename1
filename0 filename2
filename1 filename1
filename1 filename2
filename2 filename2
```

I am using openbabel's [confabreport](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3DStructureGen/multipleconformers.html#confab) tool to find RMSD of structures. Is there a better way of doing this in bash scripting? Such as skipping a self comparison or ones that have already been compared? Or just a faster way of achieving the same thing? Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information, or if this question would be better somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to Code Review!

### Shellcheck

Use the amazing [shellcheck utility](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to verify for common practices when writing bash/shell scripts. It reports missing shebang.

### Loop using seq

Since you know the lower and upper bounds, and those are pure integers, use the `seq` command to iterate through them. You won't need to do custom increments and variable swaps.

### Inner loop

Begin your inner loop with a value starting from current outer loop value + 1.

### Variable

Using more descriptive variable names helps in understanding your code.

### Parallelization

To achieve faster results, you can maybe use `parallel` to do the diff comparison for different files. If the set of files are small, you can also run the `obabel` tool in background, or disown the command from script entirely (depending on your requirements).

---

```
#!/bin/bash

LOWER_BOUND=0
UPPER_BOUND=2

for i in $(seq "$LOWER_BOUND" "$UPPER_BOUND")
do
    ((INNER_START=i+1))
    for j in $(seq "$INNER_START" "$UPPER_BOUND")
    do
        obabel "filename${i}.xyz" -oconfabreport -xf "filename${j}.xyz" -xr 0.2 > "Results.${i}.${j}"
    done
done
```

I'll leave parallelization to your own implementation. You can refer [this excellent demonstration](https://youtu.be/P40akGWJ_gY?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1) of parallel command.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! And thanks for the thorough response as well!